# Регулярное выражение для парсинга параметров в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В текст статьи есть возможность вставлять коды следующего вида

```
#FUNC:PARAM1;PARAM2#
```

Здесь `FUNC` - имя функции, а `PARAM_N` - параметр. Сейчас такие вставки определяются при помощи следующей конструкции:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    [
        "/#FUNC1#/is"
        "/#FUNC2:([\d]+);([\d]+)#/is"
    ],
    ...
)
```

Но это неудобно. Какие-то функции могут быть без параметров, какие-то - иметь любое количество параметров, и не только целочисленных. Подскажите, если есть, регулярное выражение, которое охватит сразу все варианты:

1. Функции без параметров.
2. Функции со строковыми параметрами, разделенными символом ";".
3. Любое количество параметров.
4. Любое имя функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы про что-то такое? Ищите регулярками все конструкции между `##`. Вычленяете имя функции и строку параметров целиком. Параметры разделяете по разделителю уже в колбэке. Вызываеет искомую функцию, если таковая имеется, с переданными аргументами.

```
$txt = "qweqweqwe #xxx:1;qwe# adadasdsd #yyy#";

$res = preg_replace_callback("/#(?<func>\w+)(:(?<params>.*?))?#/", function($m){
            if(function_exists($m['func'])) {
                $params = explode(';', $m['params'] ?? "");
                return call_user_func_array($m[1], $params) ;
            }
            throw new \Exception("{$m[func]} does not exists");
        }, $txt);

echo $res;


function xxx($a,$b){ return "$a-$b"; }
function yyy(){ return 'zzz'; }
```

*зы: имена функций таки лучше проверять по какому-то белому списку,а то так и до `#unlink:/www/.../....#` недалеко.*

Comment: проблема собственно будет, когда параметр-строка содержит либо разделитель `;` или ограничитель `#`. Но не ясно, быбывает у вас такое или нет. и вообще строковые литералы берутся в кавычки либо просто текстом указываются.

Comment: Спасибо, да, это то, что нужно. Функции простые - разделителей внутри быть не должно. Про `unlink` хорошо замечено.